# mysql get string to left of a character and compare it with another column

Tags: mysql, string-comparison, split

I am running this sql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT  a.user_login, a.user_email, c.domain
FROM wp_users a
JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.id = b.user_id
JOIN wp_blogs c ON b.meta_value = c.site_id
WHERE meta_key =  'primary_blog' and
ORDER BY  `a`.`ID` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Results

```
user_login        user_email                domain
abc               xys@example.com           laskdlasd.com
cdestefano        cdestefano@example.com    kaskdjkasjdkasd
fran              fran@example.com          kasdllasdlasd
```

I want only the rows in which the user_login does not equal to the string before @, i.e from the above result i only need the below row

```
abc               xys@example.com           laskdlasd.com
```

I tried the below code, but its not working

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_login, a.user_email, c.domain
FROM wp_users a
JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.id = b.user_id
JOIN wp_blogs c ON b.meta_value = c.site_id
WHERE meta_key =  'primary_blog'
AND a.user_login != LEFT( a.user_email, LOCATE(  '@', a.user_email ) ) 
ORDER BY  `a`.`ID` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

How to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Add this on the `WHERE` clause,

```
AND SUBSTRING(REPLACE(user_email, user_login, ''), 1, 1) <> '@'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_users a
JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.id = b.user_id
JOIN wp_blogs c ON b.meta_value = c.site_id
WHERE user_login  != substring_index(user_email,'@',1)
```